# Activate Windows with GVLK key without internet

Tags: windows, kms

I have several machines that are not connected directly to the internet. They use a HTTP(s) proxy that allows them to visit websites.

The machines are currently not activated because of this. The machines are loaded with a GVLK key and the KMS server is in another network.

What would be the correct approach to activate those machines? I can temporarily connect them to internet, but I read online that GVLK tries to reactivate every 7 days which is unacceptable.

I tried setting up a linux machine that is connected to internet and relays KMS requests to the actual KMS server, but that does not work either unfortunately.

Comment: Run a KMS server that will authenticate them locally ?

Comment: Impossible, to setup a KMS server I need to pay for the kms host key. There already is a KMS host setup in a different network that I need to access to prevent additional (double) costs

Comment: VLK keys usually are provided in KMS and MAK version. There are plenty of other solutions. KMS keys wouldn’t be used in anything less than an enterprise setup, so I’m sure it is not an issue to establish a VPN between two sites.

Comment: So why is it that you can't allow these machines to connect to the network where the KMS server is? That would be the simplest solution.

Comment: I have to follow a specific design. I'm basically hoping that someone on serverfault can provide me with a solution so the design does not have to be redone. I gave up all hope and am convinced the design is wrong, but maybe there's someone who knows a solution. Also, I don't have access to the other network where the KMS server is hosted and a VPN can also not be established to it.

Comment: Why don't you allow them to connect to Microsoft activation servers too via that proxy server to activate using the MAK keys?

Comment: Good one, but I don't have access to the MAK key. I don't manage the KMS server.